# routeProvider in angularJS not acting right

Tags: angularjs

Within my view I am outputting links. When I go to click a link it triggers the otherwise method in my routeProvider and ends up redirecting back to home. I need it to redirect indiv id and I need to be able to grab project.id from my view within my controller. May I please have some assistance. I'm kind of stuck.

My view:

```
<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="pagename sixteen columns fadeInUp animated">
        <h1 style="font-family: Merriweather">Portfolio</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container clearfix" ng-controller="portfolioController">
            <ul style="padding-left: 20pt" class="large-block-grid-4 align-center">
            <li class="part" ng-repeat="project in projects">
                <a href="#/indiv?id={{ project.id }}">
                    <img src="{{ project.screenshot_uri }}" alt="">
                </a>
                <br><br>
                <h4>{{ project.project_name }}</h4>
                <p>{{ project.description }}</p>
            </li>
            </ul>
</div><br><br>
```

My app data:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']).config(function($httpProvider, $routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'index.php/projects/projects/home',
        controller: 'homeController'
    });
  $routeProvider.when('/portfolio', {
    templateUrl: 'index.php/projects/projects/portfolio',
    controller: 'portfolioController'
  });
  $routeProvider.when('/indiv:id', {
    templateUrl: 'index.php/projects/projects/indiv',
    controller: 'indiv_controller'
  });
  $routeProvider.when('/contact', {
    templateUrl: 'index.php/projects/projects/contact',
    controller: 'contactController'
  });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
});

app.factory('pull_projects', function($http) {
  return {
    get_projects: function(callback) {
      $http.get('index.php/projects/pull_projects').success(callback);
    }
  };
});

app.controller('portfolioController', function($http, $location, $scope, pull_projects) {
    pull_projects.get_projects(function(results) {
      $scope.projects = results;
  });
});

app.controller('contactController', function($http, $location, $scope) {
});

app.controller('indiv_controller', function($http, $location, $scope, $routeParams) {
  alert($routeParams.id);
});

app.controller('homeController', function($http, $location, $scope) {
});
```

Comment: Should that be: `$routeProvider.when('/indiv/:id'`?

Comment: `href="#/indiv?id={{ project.id }}"` - should this be different?

Comment: `href="#/indiv/{{ project.id }}"` would correspond to `$routeProvider.when('/indiv/:id'`

Comment: Ahh, that was the problem. It works now, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is that you are defining the angular routing url and the url in the markup slightly different.

**Route:**
In the route url you are defining `/indiv:id`.  However, this would match a url where the id was part of the `indiv` part.  So, `http://host/indiv123`.

So, I would suggest changing this to: `/indiv/:id`.  This will then match urls like this: `http://host/indiv/123`.

**Markup:**
In the HTML you are declaring the url as `#/indiv?id={{ project.id }}`.  This will produce the url: `/indiv?id=123`.

To match our new angular route we need the template to be `#/indiv/{{ project.id }}` so that we produce a url like `/indiv/123`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use :

```
ng-href="#/indiv?id={{ project.id }}"
```

instead of

```
href="#/indiv?id={{ project.id }}"
```

This ensures that {{ project.id }} is correctly resolved before it is used as a link.

This occurs because Angular not always gets the chance to intercept the data binding requests before the browser attempts to resolve href and src (<img src="">) attributes. Accordingly, you should use  ng-src for images.